# What's the difference between requiring ts-node and ts-node/register

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor, commonjs

I'm doing some e2e tests for an angular app using protractor and typescript. During the setup i found out that i have to use:

require("ts-node/register")

Since I'm new to node.js I'm wondering why the "/register" is needed here and why i can't just use require("ts-node")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you want to load in your file:

- `require("ts-node")` loads the whole `ts-node` library. You can then access the `register` sub module by doing `tsNode.register`
- `require("ts-node/register")` only loads the sub module `register` of the `ts-node` library

Keep in mind that `require("ts-node")` increases the size of the bundle of the application as the whole library is loaded, so prefer the notation `require("ts-node/register")` to load only what you need.

Comment: but doesn't this mean my code should in theory also work if I remove "/register"? O'm not at my computer at the moment but I think it failed whrn i tried this first.

Comment: Yes it should work in both cases. If you use the `require("ts-node")` notation, you will have to get the sub module `register` with `const register = tsNode.register`